# Windows boot menu hd0 msdos3 not found Please help!

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows, support

2 days ago i formated all hdd drive (i have 1GBhdd and 550GBsdd) where was my windows 10 to fully get over to linux BUT after a couple of days of sweating under this system i decided to go over windows 7 AND when i reboot system and choose windows boot manager (to lauch iso from usb) BUT there error: диск "hd0, msdos3" not found. press any button to continue[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4sml.jpg)
here is log; http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/JzRTYjWgb8/
there some russian language in boot-info and url:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/JzRTYjWgb8/

Вы можете перезагрузить компьютер.
Пожалуйста, не забудьте выставить значение начальной загрузки BIOS из файла nvme0n1p1/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi!
В случае, если вы всё ещё испытываете проблемы с загрузкой, отправьте этот URL на:
boot.repair@gmail.com либо на ваш любимый форум поддержки.

i break my head under this about 2 days PLEASE HELP!! I will die if this thing will not work I tried reboot in bios and set legacy support and legacy first but he not see my usb drive even after reboot and so programms like book-info but looks like nothing help at all ;(